# Actively convert seconds to milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I currently have a setup that makes seconds and converts them to a H:mm:ss format using moment duration format.

```
formatSeconds(sec) {
    return moment.duration(sec, 'seconds').format('H:mm:ss', { trim: false });
}
```

the amount of seconds comes from my backend server. Now I also want to get the milliseconds only using the seconds.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
formatMilliseconds(sec) {
    return moment.duration(sec, 'seconds').format('H:mm:ss:S', { trim: false });
}
```

Comment: Multiply by a thousand?

Comment: like this? return moment.duration(sec * 1000, 'milliseconds').format('H:mm:ss:S', { trim: false });
this will always give me 0 at milliseconds position

Comment: if sec is an integer with no numbers after the point then it's logical result, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I was just trying out what torazaburo said.

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't look valid... shouldn't it be `function formatMilliseconds(sec) { ...`? And a moment duration doesn't have a format method, only moments do... so how does your first method work?

Comment: it's actually a method of a class. I should've included that. According to the moment duration format documentation it does have a format method (https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

Comment: okay, I see... I thought you were just using the moment.js library. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a number of seconds as an integer the milliseconds will always be 0. The only way to get milliseconds is to pass in a fraction of a second.

Example:
`formatMilliSeconds(32501.2)`

Now the output is:
`9:01:41:200`

Comment: If I simply pass in seconds to my method it will still display 0 for the milliseconds. If I pass in seconds * 1000 it will also display 0

Comment: That's because it is 0. You are passing in a number of seconds so the milliseconds will always be 0. The only way to get milliseconds is to do this - `moment.duration(val).format...` with the val being the duration in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, I know. And that is my question. How do I get the duration in milliseconds from seconds.

Comment: And there's my problem. I'm only able to get the full seconds.

Comment: If all you get is full seconds then formatting it to show milliseconds is entirely meaningless as you will always have 0 milliseconds (the server must be rounding or truncating the milliseconds and only providing the seconds - if you need milliseconds you will have to get that changed on the backend server).

Comment: isn't there another way to do this?
My idea was that on the start of every new second it counts up the milliseconds and appends it to the second but I have no idea on how should do that

Comment: Wouldn't that be sort of meaningless? The server is likely truncating the time (rounding or dropping the milliseconds). For you to try to add it on would be a very rough approximation anyway. If the requirement needs millisecond accuracy you will only get that if the server provides it or you measure time entirely on the client box (needs to be managed in one place only).